# How to identify type of asbestos used in home?

Tags: asbestos

How can I tell if the asbestos used in my home is amosite (brown), crocidolite (blue),  chrysotile (white), actinolite, anthophyllite, or tremolite? Also, how would I know if it was used, say, just in the ceiling, or also in the walls, or in the flooring. As asbestos is a type of stone, if the building uses asbestos then does it man the entire wall is made of asbestos instead of concrete or is it just used to cover three walls?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any specific concern?  Do you already have some knowledge that you do, in fact, have some asbestos in your home?

Answer (score 2):

Get it tested by an asbestos testing company. Dealing with asbestos is generally not a DIY task and is best left to the professionals. This includes testing.

Comment: I agree that testing needs to be done by the pros but it can be a DIY job if allowed and will save tens of thousands in some cases. The color mentioned by the op is not usually apparent and in some cases there is no visible color.

Comment: @mmathis, We don't even know what "it" is.  Or why knowing the specific type of asbestos that may or may not be present is important.  This could very well be a DIY task.